# Coroutine not respecting mutex.lock hence more than one coroutine entering the critical-section at a time

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I have a shared piece of code in a function, that should be accessed one at a time . I used **mutex.lock/unlock** to achieve this while working with coroutines.

```
 public class TestAbc {
 val mutex = Mutex()
    suspend fun testfunction() {
        mutex.lock()
        arrayList.add("abc")
        hashmap.put("abc", "efg")
        mutex.unlock()
    }
}



public class InitiatorClass{
val testAbc: TestAbc = TestAbc()

    public fun startJob() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            testAbc.testfunction()
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this by calling Start Job Function twice from a java class ,from different threads.

wanted only one coroutine to access critical-section at once,  with help of mutex but its not working.I see multiple coroutines entering the lock.

Comment: You can use [mutex.withLock](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html#mutual-exclusion). Are you sure the mutex isn't working? It must.

Comment: @Valeriy yeah , not working i tested it.

Comment: Could you please add more details to the question, how did you test the mutex? Also, notice, that you must wrap the code between lock and unlock into try/catch, if you don't use `withLock` function.

Comment: @ Valeriy i  have updated the code , on how i tested it .yeah would wrap it with try/catch

Comment: How do you know that they are entering the critical section *at the same time*?

Comment: i had added log just after mutex.lock() and before mutex.unlock(), so every mutex.lock should be followed by mutex.unlock.But i was seeing two consecutive mutex.lock and  then two consecutive mutex.unlock in logs sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Bad, I was creating Multiple Instance of the Class **InitiatorClass**.
When i corrected it , everything works Fine .